# firebase get id token expire after one hour how will be call the token automatically when it is expire?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting id token but token is expired after an hour.i am trying to handle token when it is expire, how It can be called automatically when  it is expired. Can anyone help me. thankx

```
func signInWithCustomToken(customToken:String){
        Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: customToken ) { (user, error) in
               user?.user.getIDToken(completion: { (token, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    // Handle error
                    print("getIDToken error: \(error)")
                    return;
                }

            print("ID Token\(token)")

            })


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the built-in providers, Firebase will automatically refresh the ID token before it expires.

But since you're using a custom token, there is no way to for the Firebase client to auto-refresh that. You will have to do so yourself.

Comment: so how I can refresh custom id token when it expires ?

Comment: Since it is a custom token, you'll just mint a new ID token after say 55 minutes, the same way you created the initial ID token. That's pretty much what the Firebase clients do too.

Comment: is there any delegate methods which called when token is expired? or we had to handle manually like after 55 minutes  it should  be updated

Comment: You'll have to handle this yourself in code. When you get the ID token, check when it expires and set a timer to fire a bit before that so that you can refresh the token before it expires.